# How to deactivate the username quickly

Tags: administration, admin

One manager recently left the company and I received the urgent request to deactive his username. Because the manager was part of several approval processes , for me it is taking longer than expected. is any other way to quickly resolve this issue like change of email address or profile or record or any suggestion. Thanks..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can freeze the user.

> In some cases, you can’t immediately deactivate an account, such as
>   when a user is selected in a custom hierarchy field. To prevent users
>   from logging in to your organization while you perform the steps to
>   deactivate them, you can freeze user accounts.
>
> From Setup, enter Users in the Quick Find box, then select Users.
>   Click the username of the account you want to freeze. Click Freeze to
>   block access to the account or Unfreeze to allow access to the account
>   again.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=users_freeze.htm&type=5